# EOLs -- need help

Tags: components

Does anyone here know, perhaps a website, magazine, quarterly, or anything at all that may tell you when specific products may have been discontinued?  I receive some things from MFGs such as Renesas ... but I didn't know if there was an industry standard to this.

I am trying to be pro-active, and not be a drone.  I understand I could call a specific mfg or specialist and get the information, but I just would like to know if anyone knows of a specific site.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a distributor, they can send you notification on parts you have used are going EOL. They can also check for specific parts or an entire BOM.

There are also services which do this. Since there are so many possible parts, these services aren't free.

I wouldn't waste timing looking for a magazine or quarterly, you aren't likely to find such.